# Why CTAD failed for std::unique_ptr(new int()) in C++17?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, ctad

Why C++17 class template argument deduction failed for 
`std::unique_ptr(new int());`

What could the compiler imagine it to be rather than `std::unique_ptr<int>`?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr(new int[100])` - It's still a pointer being passed in, but the correct type should be `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`

Comment: You appear to have been [vexed by a parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). ;3

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - This is a new expression, `int()` designates a value initialized integer.